# ngModel is not correctly updated in Internet Explorer - AngularJS 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-ng-model

Hello I have strange issue that only appears in IE 11 with angular 1.3.

I have a directive which allows me to store `Object` as `ngModel` value of `input` element. It works without any problem with AngularJS 1.2, but it doesn't work with AngularJS 1.3 (only in the Internet Explorer).

It is simply code:

```
elem.on('input', function(){
   var val = elem.val();
    ngModel.$setViewValue({
        'sampleData': new Date().getTime(),
        'value': val
    });
    scope.$apply();
});
```

When I type text in IE, the input sets correct object as model value for some milliseconds but next changes it into string. In other browsers it updates `ngModel` correctly.

You can see this strange behavior there:

AngularJS 1.2: http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/e6Lvpqj3/ (works in IE, Chrome, and Firefox),

AngularJS 1.3: http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/mvx9dbyu/2/ (**doesn't work in IE 11**, works in Chrome and Firefox)

What is the reason and how can I fix it?

It is my whole directive:

```
app.directive('myInput',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {},
        priority: 1,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){
            elem.off('input');
            elem.off('change');

            ngModel.$render = function(){
                var model = {
                    'sampleData': 'sampleData',
                    value: ''
                }                                   
                ngModel.$setViewValue(model);
                elem.val(model.value);
            }

            elem.on('input', function(){
               var val = elem.val();
                ngModel.$setViewValue({
                    'sampleData': new Date().getTime(),
                    value: val
                });
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: @BobDoleForPresident IE 11

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mvx9dbyu/5/ - I am not sure scope.$apply failing or not, because I cannot open developer console on my ie 11.

Comment: @YOU, thanks, it works fine - no digest error in the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular 1.3 has some kind of hack for `input` event for IE browsers. Please analyse `$SnifferProvider.hasEvent` function. This function is used within inputDirective to guarantee the correct viewValue for browsers which does not support `input` event. Workaround is based on `keydown` event which is widely supported.

To fix your code example for IE simple turn of `keydown` event to disable all triggers.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){
        elem.off('input');
        elem.off('change');
        elem.off('keydown');
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the root of this problem!!  For anyone in a similar situation: in my case, setting the model to update on keydown instead of the default (`ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'keydown' }"` on the element) gave me the behavior I wanted.  I had other directives on the input element, so YMMV.